# Installing ros-melodic-ros-base deletes npm, installing npm deletes ros. How can I have both?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I inherited a system that needs both ROS and npm to be complete. I had to re-flash the embedded computer that they were running on, and so now I am reinstalling and reconfiguring everything. However, when I run sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-base, it deletes npm during installation. When I run sudo apt install npm, it deletes all of my ros stuff during installation. The person that set it up before doesn't know why this is happening, so he is unable to help me get both packages installed.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to have both? I will gladly give more detail if necessary, just let me know.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329144/installing-ros-melodic-ros-base-deletes-npm,-installing-npm-deletes-ros.-how-can-i-have-both?/) by [tzinke](https://answers.ros.org/users/44182/tzinke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-07-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got around the issue by installing nodejs and npm using these three commands:

```
sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Not entirely sure why `sudo apt-get install npm` was problematic. Hopefully that helps someone other than myself!

---

Originally posted by [tzinke](https://answers.ros.org/users/44182/tzinke/) with karma: 56 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hardesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54551/hardesh/) on 2020-05-07**:
Thanks! This worked for me...

**Comment by [Lingaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27310/lingaa/) on 2020-05-28**:
Thanks. The commands 2, 3 worked for me. nodejs is installed

**Comment by [daniyalyasin93](https://answers.ros.org/users/41613/daniyalyasin93/) on 2021-03-14**:
This solution didn't work for me, as it still requires libssl1.0-dev to install nodejs-dev, which is required by npm. And libssl1.0-dev wipes out ROS

**Comment by [bach](https://answers.ros.org/users/66642/bach/) on 2021-08-24**:
I also have problems. nodejs is ok with `sudo apt install nodejs`, but if I try to install the npm depencies, in particular libssl1.0-dev, it will delete ROS packages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that there are conflicting dependencies like in this issue: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/19845

You can ask apt to tell you more about why it's uninstalling the other one when it does so. You should copy and paste the output into your question for more help.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1